# sound receiving Not working in Coredova Related app is having ios Framework

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ios-library

**sound receiving Not working in Coredova Related app is having ios Framework(supports Sending and Receiving Tone)?**

- i have framework, that will supports Sending and receiving the Sound

  - When I integrated same  `framework` in `native app` ,its `receiving` sound , that will played by the `sender app`
- Here the issue is `sound` is `not receiving` from `sender app` in ***coredova Related hybrid application***

**how can resolve this issue????**

Comment: Your question is unclear...please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.Please show your effort too.